# Creating a snowflake python stored procedure with Terraform

Tags: python, stored-procedures, terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to use Terraform to create and deploy a python stored procedure in snowflake.

I have been able to create a python stored proc by hand via worksheets or jupyter and snowpark.

Via Terraform documentation I tried to deploy the following

```
resource "snowflake_procedure" "proc" {
  name                = "sp_stg_to_raw_sample"
  database            = module.raw_table_sample.database_name
  schema              = module.raw_table_sample.schema_name
  language            = "PYTHON"
  runtime_version     = "3.8"
  packages            = ["snowflake-snowpark-python"]
  handler             = "filter_by_role"
  return_type         = "TABLE()"
  execute_as          = "CALLER"
  statement           = <<EOT
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col

def filter_by_role(session, table_name, role):
  df = session.table(table_name)
  return df.filter(col("role") == role)
EOT
}
```

But I have the following error

Error: error creating procedure sp_stg_to_raw_sample err = 391531 (42601): SQL compilation error: An active warehouse is required for creating Python stored procedures.
on raw_sp_sample.tf line 12, in resource "snowflake_procedure" "proc":
12: resource "snowflake_procedure" "proc" {

I tried adding a warehouse in the terraform config with no success.

Would you know a way to solve this issue ?

Many thanks

Comment: Try assigning a default warehouse to the terraform user with alter user username set DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE = warehousename; and ensure that the wh has auto_resume = true;